# Couchdb mango query speed

Tags: couchdb

I have following type of documents:

```
{
  "_id": "0710b1dd6cc2cdc9c2ffa099c8000f7b",
  "_rev": "1-93687d40f54ff6ca72e66ca7fc99caff",
  "date": "2018-06-04T07:46:08.848Z",
  "topic": "some topic",
}
```

The collection is not very large. Only 20k documents.

However, the following query is very slow. Takes ca 5 secs!

```
{ 
  selector: {
    topic: 'some topic'
  },
  sort: ['date'],
}
```

I tried various indexes, e.g.

```
index: {
  fields: ['topic', 'date']
}
```

but nothing really worked well.

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

When sorting in a Mango query, you need to ensure that the sort order you are asking for matches the index that you are using.

If you are indexing the data set in `topic,date` order then you can use the following query on "topic" to get the data out in data order using the index:

```
{
   "selector": {
      "topic": "some topic"
   },
   "sort": [
      "topic",
      "date"
   ]
}
```

Because the sort matches the form of the data in the index, the index is used to answer the query which should speed up your query time considerably.